# How to do a boxplot bases in rows values instead of column values

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have some score data from a game I'm playing with friends, it looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
                   'Score1' : [100, 150, 110, 180, 125], 
                   'Score2' : [200, 210, np.nan, 125, 293],
                   'Score3' : [50, 35, 200, 100, 180]})
```

If I do a `df.boxplot()` I'll get a boxplot based on the Score#, that is, based in the scores of the whole community:

[image]

Now I want to do a boxplot() for each player, so we can see how they rank against each other. Something like this:

[image]

First thing I tried was to do a boxplot of the traspose matrix:

```
df.T.boxplot()
```

But I get an error `IndexError: list index out of range`

I think it has to do with the indexes created in the traspose, so I have been playing with them, but I really don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to set the index as player

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Player' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
                   'Score1' : [100, 150, 110, 180, 125], 
                   'Score2' : [200, 210, np.nan, 125, 293],
                   'Score3' : [50, 35, 200, 100, 180]})
df = df.set_index('Player')
print df
df.T.boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys, you're awesome. I spend at least half an hour with this, and it was so simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
tdf = df.set_index('Player').T
tdf.boxplot()
plt.show()
```

[image]